# Authentication between microservice

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication

I have two microservices (or more) that communicate with each other. Now, I need an authentication between them.

Note: 
I do not want authentication with a human being (user). 
I do not want to pass the token of a user between two or more microservices.
what if I want is authentication between two or more applications in server, in fact there is no interaction with users.

I want to do something similar to what google does, where you get a **client-id** and an **api-key** to authenticate with the Google APIs.

I have a master application that receives requests from other applications with automatic processes that run on other servers, I need to validate who those applications are (**client-id**) and if they have authorization to perform the operation

I'm working on typescript

Comment: I would suggest that if you need to authenticate between your microservices that you'll need to write some code that authenticates between your microservices

Comment: @KenWhite haha, thank you very much for the help, edited

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: I understand @JaromandaX , at the moment I do not have anything that authenticates between my microservices, that is the problem. I searched but everything I get is related to the login of a common user (apparently no one asks that question or the other question is more important)

Comment: thanks @KenWhite , but I do not expect anyone to make my code. I hope someone tells me at least the name of a tool, or points out a route to follow, because by regular routes I only get information that is not relevant. I understand that the Stack Overflow community has more experience and at least they know what string of words I can put in google to get information that is useful for my current problem

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help] pages (as was suggested when you created your account) to familiarize yourself with this site and how it works. Asking for a tool recommendation would be off-topic here, and so is asking us to help you form a search phrase. This site is for specific questions, and *I want to do this thing. Need advice, a tool or a search phrase for Google* isn't specific at all. If you're wanting to do something with an API key and client ID, you're going to need to write an API and provide a key implementation.

Comment: interservice authentication? microservice authentication? it's hard suggesting a `string of words I can put in google` without knowing what you've already tried looking for

Comment: @KenWhite I explain a little better, my language is Spanish. in my language I get little information. I suppose that this type of authentication that I describe has a name in English with which I can get information, but I do not know it. I have searched about JWT and it is not related to what I need, I have read about AUTH2 and it is not similar to me either (although I may be wrong). but considering that I must translate English-Spanish with every data that I think I can get, my search has been complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to authenticate between several micro-services if you have control on all of them is ***sharing a secret***, you can use it to cypher with a symmetric algorithm (e.g. AES) some information (like the calling micro-service, destination, other info, ...).
The receiver can verify that the caller is legit and after do the service also return some ciphered information to be validated by the caller.

**Note:** Be aware that this information should include some random generated data (at the beginning preferably to increase entropy in cyphered data, and avoid chosen-ciphertext attack), and a timestamp (to avoid reuse).

Another approach could be, to generate Certificates for all micro-services and connect them using double authentication ciphered channel, you can have all the authentication you need, plus a ciphered channel to avoid interceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to carry out tests with the use of certificates, for what you comment seems to be the safe solution

Comment: Tu puedes crear tus propios certificados si lo deseas, usando la herramienta de Java `keytool` o también `openssl` autofirmados

Comment: si, ahora se que camino puedo seguir. usaré `openssl` para generar los certificados